# C/C++: emulating restrict keyword by copying arguments to local variables

Tags: c++, c, gcc, avx, restrict

I encountered the following question when using vector intrinsics (AVX), but the question probably also applies to sequential programming. It concerns the use of the `restrict` keyword. The keyword is available in C99, but not in C++ (except for special keywords provided by most compilers). My question is: Can I avoid using `restrict` by copying data from non-`restrict` pointer arguments to local variables? It works in my example, but is this behavior guaranteed?

Here's my code with 4 different versions of SIMD vector addition. The first version `vecAdd1()` passes the arguments as `restrict` pointers. All other versions use normal (non-`restrict`) pointers as arguments. The second version `vecAdd2()` has no further code modifications. The third version `vecAdd3()` copies the `data` pointer of each struct into a local variable. The fourth version `vecAdd4()` also does the same for the size `n`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

#define N 8 // 8 floats per AVX vector
#define SIZE 1000 // 1000 floats per data vector

typedef struct { int n; float *data; } Vec;

void vecCreate(int size, Vec *v) {
  v->n = size;
  posix_memalign((void**)&(v->data), 32, size * sizeof(float));
}


void vecAdd1(Vec * restrict a, Vec * restrict b, Vec * restrict c) {
  __m256 va, vb, vc;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (a->n - N); i += N) {
    va = _mm256_load_ps(a->data + i);
    vb = _mm256_load_ps(b->data + i);
    vc = _mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm256_store_ps(c->data + i, vc);
  }
}

void vecAdd2(Vec *a, Vec *b, Vec *c) {
  __m256 va, vb, vc;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (a->n - N); i += N) {
    va = _mm256_load_ps(a->data + i);
    vb = _mm256_load_ps(b->data + i);
    vc = _mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm256_store_ps(c->data + i, vc);
  }
}

void vecAdd3(Vec *a, Vec *b, Vec *c) {
  __m256 va, vb, vc;
  float *pa = a->data, *pb = b->data, *pc = c->data;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (a->n - N); i += N) {
    va = _mm256_load_ps(pa + i);
    vb = _mm256_load_ps(pb + i);
    vc = _mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm256_store_ps(pc + i, vc);
  }
}

void vecAdd4(Vec *a, Vec *b, Vec *c) {
  __m256 va, vb, vc;
  float *pa = a->data, *pb = b->data, *pc = c->data;
  int ae = a->n - N;
  for (int i = 0; i <= ae; i += N) {
    va = _mm256_load_ps(pa + i);
    vb = _mm256_load_ps(pb + i);
    vc = _mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm256_store_ps(pc + i, vc);
  }
}



int
main()
{
  Vec a, b, c;
  vecCreate(1000, &a);
  vecCreate(1000, &b);
  vecCreate(1000, &c);
  vecAdd1(&a, &b, &c);
  vecAdd2(&a, &b, &c);
  vecAdd3(&a, &b, &c);
  vecAdd4(&a, &b, &c);
  printf("%g\n", c.data[123]);
  return 0;
}
```

(Just a comment: The `-N` and `<=` is used to limit processing to the part where entire SIMD vectors can be loaded and stored. I omitted the sequential postamble.)

Here's the compiler invocation:

```
gcc -O3 -mno-avx256-split-unaligned-load -mno-avx256-split-unaligned-store -march=native -masm=intel -save-temps -std=c99 -Wall -o vecadd vecadd.c
```

I'm using version 7.5.0. In the following I only show the relevant portions of the assembly code from `vecadd.s`.

In `vecAdd1()`, the loop has a very efficient implementation: load one SIMD vector, add the second, store to result, advance pointer, check for loop end:

```
.L5:
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax], ymm0
    add rax, 32
    cmp rdx, rax
    jne .L5
```

If I leave out the `restrict` keyword in the argument list in `vecAdd2()`, the loop gets very inefficient: Within the loop, the three `data` pointers and the size `n` are reloaded every time, before the SIMD vectors are loaded, processed, and stored, and the loop condition is checked:

```
.L10:
    mov r10, QWORD PTR 8[rdi]
    mov r9, QWORD PTR 8[rsi]
    add r8d, 8
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR 8[rdx]
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [r10+rax]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [r9+rax]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax], ymm0
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    add rax, 32
    sub ecx, 7
    cmp ecx, r8d
    jg  .L10
```

In version `vecAdd3()`, the `data` pointers are not reloaded (they are loaded once before the loop), but the size `n` is reloaded:

```
.L15:
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR -32[r8+rax*4]
    mov ecx, eax
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR -32[rsi+rax*4]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR -32[r9+rax*4], ymm0
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    add rax, 8
    sub edx, 7
    cmp edx, ecx
    jg  .L15
```

Only if I copy all `data` pointers and `n` to local variables in `vecAdd4()`, the code looks like the one in `vecAdd1()`:

```
.L20:
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [r8+rax], ymm0
    add rax, 32
    cmp rdx, rax
    jne .L20
```

So, to repeat my question: Assume I want to avoid the compiler-specific `restrict` replacements in C++. I therefore use non-`restrict` arguments, but copy them to local (also non-`restrict`) variables. Is it guaranteed that the compiler doesn't assume for the local variables that they can alias (even if the function arguments can)?

(Side question: Is it relevant for this question that I copy struct components?)

Comment: Yes, it does work around extra levels of indirection for small scalar objects (which you maybe should have just passed by value in the first place here, just one int and one pointer), but of course whole arrays are too large to copy.  BTW, putting the pointer member first would lead to padding at the end instead of middle, more efficient arg-passing in x86-64 System V I think if you did pass by value.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I checked it: Passing the three Vec arguments by value actually produces efficient code. In real-life code that would be impossible though, since the result (`c`) is typically reallocated inside the function.

Comment: You could return a new `c` instead of modifying the pointed-to object, if that pattern works at all for your code.

Answer (score 2):

In general local variables can not achieve the same optimization capabilities as aliasing directives like `restrict`.

E.g. imagine that loop in `vecAdd4` is unrolled by compiler:

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= ae / 2; i += 2*N) {
    va_1 = _mm256_load_ps(pa + i);
    vb_1 = _mm256_load_ps(pb + i);
    vc_1 = _mm256_add_ps(va_1, vb_1);
    _mm256_store_ps(pc + i, vc_1);
    va_2 = _mm256_load_ps(pa + i + 1);
    vb_2 = _mm256_load_ps(pb + i + 1);
    vc_2 = _mm256_add_ps(va_2, vb_2);
    _mm256_store_ps(pc + i + 1, vc_2);
  }
```

In this case it's unable to move `va_2` and `va_3` loads before the first `_mm256_store_ps` intrinsic (to hide latency) because of potential aliasing between `pa + i` and `pc + i`.

Assuming that all `a`, `b`, `c`, `pa`, `pb` and `pc` do not alias, I'd suggest to mark them as such:

```
void vecAdd5(Vec * restrict a, Vec * restrict b, Vec * restrict c) {
  __m256 va, vb, vc;
  float * restrict pa = a->data, * restrict pb = b->data, * restrict pc = c->data;
  for (int i = 0; i <= a->n - N; i += N) {
    va = _mm256_load_ps(pa + i);
    vb = _mm256_load_ps(pb + i);
    vc = _mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm256_store_ps(pc + i, vc);
  }
}
```

This achieves the same assembly as `vecAdd4` with much less manual work:

```
        vmovaps ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax*4]
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax*4]
        vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax*4], ymm0
        add     rax, 8
        cmp     edx, eax
        jg      .L3
```

Comment: Interesting aspect, thanks. I added -funroll-all-loops, but to me the unrolled loops of `vecAdd1()` and `vecAdd4()` look the same in assembly.

Comment: Just a correction: In your manually unrolled code, should that be `+N` instead of `+1`?

Comment: As you observe, whether `a`, `b`, and `c` alias each other is not indicative of whether `a->data`, `b->data`, and `c->data` alias each other, `restrict` or no.  `restrict`-qualifying `pa`, `pb`, and `pc` might indeed permit wanted optimizations, but that does place a restriction on callers that is not conveyed by the function signature, and thus cannot be checked by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I avoid using restrict by copying data from non-restrict pointer
> arguments to local variables?

You can avoid using `restrict` simply by not using `restrict`.  There are no circumstances that *require* `restrict`-qualification.  It's more the other way around: `restrict` qualification places requirements on *other* code.

The advantage of `restrict` is that it allows the compiler to make stronger assumptions than otherwise it could do, so as -- at its exclusive discretion -- to perform optimizations that otherwise might result in non-conforming behavior.

The compiler can often make similar assumptions about local variables, and about locals with respect to globals and the targets of pointer arguments, and in that sense yes, making local copies can sometimes enable the compiler to perform the same stronger optimizations that `restrict` affords, at the expense of making the copy in the first place.

It should also be observed that `restrict`-qualification is *shallow*.  For example, the `restrict`-qualification in your `vecAdd1()` case requires the caller to ensure that the (pointer) arguments associated with parameters `a`, `b`, and `c` do not alias each other, but it does not require that the `data` pointers stored in the pointed-to `Vec` objects point to different or non-overlapping arrays.

> It works in my example, but is this
> behavior guaranteed?

**As general considerations**,

- If you write conforming code, then you can rely on a conforming information to exhibit conforming externally-visible behavior.  In this sense, however, externally-visible behavior does not include running time.  The C language provides no basis ever to rely  on particular optimizations being performed by compilers.
- Removing `restrict` qualification can change a non-conforming program into a conforming one, but the reverse is not the case.

But **with respect to the example code**, `restrict` qualification does not gain you anything useful.  The compiler might be able to more aggressively optimize if it could assume that the vector data pointed to by `a->data`, `b->data`, and `c->data` do not overlap, but the none of the `restrict` qualification nor any of the pointer copying in any of the example code permits it to make such an assumption.  It is conceivable that a compiler could use other means to come to such a non-aliasing conclusion, but nothing about of your `vecAddX()` variations contributes to that.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really useful to understand the effect of `restrict`. I just think that the explanation by Peter Cordes that the `may_alias` attribute is ultimately causing the problem is closer to the point (see the second edit to my answer below). You are right that the `restrict` qualifier at the `Vec *` is actually ineffective in my case (since the effect of `restrict` is shallow), but combined with the weird ignorance of the compiler when it sees `may_alias`, it becomes effective. Would you agree?

Comment: @Ralf, I hesitate to speculate on how GCC uses attributes to choose which optimizations it will or won't perform, but I don't think `may_alias` has any implication on which optimizations GCC *could* perform in your case.  The compiler does not need type-based analysis to know that your `va`, `vb`, and `vc` do not alias each other or the return values of `_mm256_load_ps()` or `_mm256_add_ps()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize the recent state of research:

- `vecAdd1()` uses `restrict` and `__m256` with `may_alias` with default intrincis
- `vecAdd2()` doesn't use `restrict` and `__m256` with `may_alias` with default intrinsics
- `vecAdd2x()` doesn't use `restrict`, but `x__m256` without `may_alias` with modified intrinsics

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

typedef float x__m256 __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32)));

extern __inline void
__attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
x_mm256_store_ps (float *__P, x__m256 __A)
{
  *(x__m256 *)__P = __A;
}

extern __inline x__m256
__attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
x_mm256_load_ps (float const *__P)
{
  return *(x__m256 *)__P;
}

extern __inline x__m256
__attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
x_mm256_add_ps (x__m256 __A, x__m256 __B)
{
  return (x__m256) ((__v8sf)__A + (__v8sf)__B);
}

#define N 8 // 8 floats per AVX vector
#define SIZE 1000 // 1000 floats per data vector

typedef struct { int n; float *data; } Vec;

void vecCreate(int size, Vec *v) {
  v->n = size;
  posix_memalign((void**)&(v->data), 32, size * sizeof(float));
}

// restrict pointer arguments
void vecAdd1(Vec * restrict a, Vec * restrict b, Vec * restrict c) {
  __m256 va, vb, vc;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (a->n - N); i += N) {
    va = _mm256_load_ps(a->data + i);
    vb = _mm256_load_ps(b->data + i);
    vc = _mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm256_store_ps(c->data + i, vc);
  }
}

// like vecAdd1, but without restrict
void vecAdd2(Vec *a, Vec *b, Vec *c) {
  __m256 va, vb, vc;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (a->n - N); i += N) {
    va = _mm256_load_ps(a->data + i);
    vb = _mm256_load_ps(b->data + i);
    vc = _mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm256_store_ps(c->data + i, vc);
  }
}

// like vecAdd2, but with x__m256 and x_mm256
void vecAdd2x(Vec *a, Vec *b, Vec *c) {
  x__m256 va, vb, vc;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (a->n - N); i += N) {
    va = x_mm256_load_ps(a->data + i);
    vb = x_mm256_load_ps(b->data + i);
    vc = x_mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    x_mm256_store_ps(c->data + i, vc);
  }
}

int
main() {
  Vec a, b, c;
  vecCreate(1000, &a);
  vecCreate(1000, &b);
  vecCreate(1000, &c);
  vecAdd1(&a, &b, &c);
  vecAdd2(&a, &b, &c);
  vecAdd2x(&a, &b, &c);
  printf("%g\n", c.data[123]);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with

```
gcc -O3 -mno-avx256-split-unaligned-load -mno-avx256-split-unaligned-store -march=native -masm=intel -save-temps -std=c99 -Wall -o vecadd vecadd.c
```

`vecAdd1()` and `vecAdd2x()` lead to efficient assembly instrucions such as

```
.L5:
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax], ymm0
    add rax, 32
    cmp rdx, rax
    jne .L5
```

whereas the code generated for `vecAdd2()` reloads `data` pointers and `n` in each iteration:

```
.L10:
    mov r10, QWORD PTR 8[rdi]
    mov r9, QWORD PTR 8[rsi]
    add r8d, 8
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR 8[rdx]
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [r10+rax]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [r9+rax]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax], ymm0
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    add rax, 32
    sub ecx, 7
    cmp ecx, r8d
    jg  .L10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only an attempt at a partial answer. I added the following version `vecAdd5()` where I copy the `Vec` pointers from the argument list to local variables, rather than the `data` pointers and `n` from the struct:

```
void vecAdd5(Vec *a, Vec *b, Vec *c) {
  __m256 va, vb, vc;
  Vec *aa = a, *bb = b, *cc = c;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (aa->n - N); i += N) {
    va = _mm256_load_ps(aa->data + i);
    vb = _mm256_load_ps(bb->data + i);
    vc = _mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm256_store_ps(cc->data + i, vc);
  }
}
```

This leads to inefficient assembly code similar to `vecAdd2()`:

```
.L25:
    mov r10, QWORD PTR 8[rdi]
    mov r9, QWORD PTR 8[rsi]
    add r8d, 8
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR 8[rdx]
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [r10+rax]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [r9+rax]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax], ymm0
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    add rax, 32
    sub ecx, 7
    cmp r8d, ecx
    jl  .L25
```

So, just copying pointers to local variables does not tell the compiler to forget about aliasing. I'm not sure if I interpret this correctly: In `vecAdd4()`, the compiler still assumes that the `Vec` pointer arguments can alias (and copying them as in `vecAdd5()` doesn't change this), so the components of one struct could change through a pointer to another one. However, it does not assume that the `data` pointers can alias once they are copied to local variables?

(I'm more confused than before: Actually, nowhere in the code of `vecAdd2()` a `data` component or `n` is modified, so why would the compiler assume that they can change and reload these components from the struct? We don't write to `n`, but only read, and never write to `data`, but only access the content of `data`.)

---

Edit in response to Peter Cordes:

If I transfer the processing to a function which receives an int and three float pointers, the assembly code is efficient:

```
void floatAdd6(int n, float *a, float *b, float *c) {
  __m256 va, vb, vc;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (n - N); i += N) {
    va = _mm256_load_ps(a + i);
    vb = _mm256_load_ps(b + i);
    vc = _mm256_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm256_store_ps(c + i, vc);
  }
}

void vecAdd6(Vec *a, Vec *b, Vec *c) {
  floatAdd6(a->n, a->data, b->data, c->data);
}
```

Here's the assembly output for `vecAdd6()` (`floatAdd6()` looks the same):

```
.L50:
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [r8+rax]
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax], ymm0
    add rax, 32
    cmp rdx, rax
    jne .L50
```

---

2nd edit in response to Peter Cordes:

I think Peter Cordes is right with his explanation that the `may_alias` attribute of the `__m256` is causing the problem. I replaced `__m256` with my own data type and a sequential implementation (which is auto-vectorized by the compiler, though):

```
typedef struct { float v[N]; } emuVec;

emuVec loadEmuVec(float *d) {
  emuVec r;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) r.v[i] = d[i];
  return r;
}

emuVec addEmuVec(emuVec a, emuVec b) {
  emuVec c;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) c.v[i] = a.v[i] + b.v[i];
  return c;        
}

void storeEmuVec(float *d, emuVec a) {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) d[i] = a.v[i];
}

void vecAdd7a(Vec *a, Vec *b, Vec *c) {
  emuVec va, vb, vc;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (a->n - N); i += N) {
    va = loadEmuVec(a->data + i);
    vb = loadEmuVec(b->data + i);
    vc = addEmuVec(va, vb);
    storeEmuVec(c->data + i, vc);
  }
}

void vecAdd7b(Vec * restrict a, Vec * restrict b, Vec *restrict c) {
  emuVec va, vb, vc;
  for (int i = 0; i <= (a->n - N); i += N) {
    va = loadEmuVec(a->data + i);
    vb = loadEmuVec(b->data + i);
    vc = addEmuVec(va, vb);
    storeEmuVec(c->data + i, vc);
  }
}
```

Here the code produced for `vecAdd7a()` (without `restrict`) and `vecAdd7b()` (with `restrict`) is exactly the same. The assembly instructions are somewhat different compared to `vecAdd1()`, but the code doesn't show the inefficient the reloading of `data` pointers and size `n` inside the loop; it is just using an additional counter and unaligned rather than aligned loads and stores:

```
.L71:
    vmovups ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax]
    add edx, 1
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax]
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR [r9+rax], ymm0
    add rax, 32
    cmp esi, edx
    ja  .L71
```

Somewhat confusing is that there is a second loop, and the code seems to decide which version to use:

```
.L73:
    vmovups ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rcx]
    add rax, 32
    add rcx, 32
    add rdx, 32
    vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR -32[rax]
    vmovups YMMWORD PTR -32[rdx], ymm0
    cmp rax, rsi
    jne .L73
```

but still there's no sign of reloading pointers and size inside the loop.

So my interpretation would be the following: If the compiler sees the `may_alias` attribute of `__m256`, it entirely abandons an analysis whether the code actually could modify one `Vec` through a pointer to another `Vec` (in the intrinsics using `__m256`). I really wonder why: It should be clear to the compiler that an access to floats via a `data` pointer could never actually modify the pointer itself nor the struct `Vec` in which it is contained, and therefore could never lead to aliasing.

---

3rd edit: I modified the replacement data type `emuVec` by adding a `may_alias` attribute:

```
typedef struct { float v[N]; } __attribute__ ((__may_alias__)) emuVec;
```

but this doesn't lead to changes in the assembly code; there's no difference between `vecAdd7a()` and `vecAdd7b()`. This casts some doubt on the conjecture that `may_alias` confuses the compiler. Could the effect of wrong aliasing assumptions made by the compiler be caused by using intrinsics?

Comment: Note that GCC/clang [define `__m256` as an `__attribute__((may_alias))` type](//stackoverflow.com/q/52112605), like `char`.  So `_mm256_store_ps` is special, and unlike other assignments, type-based aliasing can't prove that it doesn't modify a struct.  If you'd used a manually-defined `typedef float __m256 __attribute__((vector_size(32)))` without may_alias, type-based aliasing would prove that storing 8 floats can't change a `float*` (because the compiler assumes that strict-aliasing UB doesn't happen).

Comment: I see, thanks. But if that is the case, shouldn't the compiler also be worried that the `mm256_store_ps()` in `vecAdd4()` may modify the `pc` pointer and reload it in the loop from some store? I'm probably missing something...

Comment: No, `pc` is a newly-created local whose address hasn't escaped the function.  It can safely assume that none of its function args, or data pointed-to by function args, were pointing to a local that didn't even exist before the function was called; that kind of wild-pointer bug would be Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I'm still struggling with this. I edited my answer and added a new version `vecAdd6()` where I transfer the processing to a function receiving an int and non-restrict float pointers. On the one hand (with respect to your first comment) I wonder whether still the `may_alias` attribute prevents the proof that storing 8 floats can't change the float pointer (and we should see inefficient code), on the other hand probably your second comment holds (since the argument of `floatAdd6()` is like a newly-created local).

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I edited my answer a second time, replacing `__m256` (`may_alias`) with another data type. Do you think my explanation given in the edit makes sense?

Comment: @Peter Cordes: My 3rd edit above indicates that the effect may not be related to the `may_alias` attribute. Maybe the missing aliasing analysis by the compiler is caused by using intrinsics?

Comment: Your code doesn't ever do struct assignment of an object of type `emuVec`.  Your `load` and `storeEmuVec` functions use plain `float` reads or assignments on the other `float*` arg, not casting it to `emuVec*` and dereferencing.  So the attribute there doesn't come into play.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I see. Any idea how I could explore whether the `may_alias` is the cause?

Comment: Sure, by defining your own version of `__m256` with `__attribute__((vector_size(32), aligned(4)))` *without* may_alias.  Note that I declared aligned to a float, not the whole vector aligned, so dereferencing it is like a `storeu`, not `store`.  Then you do `non_aliasing_m256 v = *(non_aliasing_m256*)p;` pointer-cast + deref, exactly like you'd do with a `char*` to access bytes of an object.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks a lot. I did a similar thing affecting the entire test code: I introduced a `x__m256` without `may_alias`, and my own versions of the intrinsics `x_mm256_store_ps()` etc., all working on `x__m256` (modified from `avxintrin.h`). Then in fact the difference between `vecAdd1()` and `vecAdd2()` disappears, and both lead to efficient assembly code. So the `may_alias` is causing the problem. That leaves the question why the compiler doesn't see that, by passing the `data` pointer from `Vec` to the intrinsics, there is no way that the `Vec` arguments could influence each other.

Comment: It's legal in C and C++ to have a `float*` that actually points to a `Vec` object.  It would be strict-aliasing UB to dereference it as a `float`, but casting it to `__m256*` before dereferencing (via `_mm256_storeu_ps`) would mean that case can't be ruled out by assuming no UB.  This is not just a compiler missed-optimization; to make a good version of the loop it would have to check that `c` wasn't in the range `c->data` to `c->data + a->n` or something like that.  (Which would be a valuable optimization for this case where the source is hard to optimize, but come at the cost of code-size.)

Comment: Compilers do generate overlap checks when auto-vectorizing a normal loop with multiple input pointers, but this extra level of indirection is a step too far, and is something you can avoid in your source by reading the `float*` and `int` values into locals.  I guess I should post some of this as an answer sometime when I get around to it; it's interesting and non-trivial but I think I do fully understand what's happening in each of your cases.